# Regular expression validation in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I want to use regular expression validation (email, website, phonenumber, etc.). Then how can I do that in the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) add and edit form?